# How to re-register a one way replica geodatabase

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, versioning, replication

Long story short. Arcmap crashed during one of my regular synchronizations of a replica geodatabase created through one-way replication checkout. Upon reloading it seems to have unregistered the replica without copying the changes to the master SDE geodatabase.

We have backups of the distributed databases but it seem that the link between the modified/replicated personal gdb and our main SDE database has been broken.

Does anyone know of any fixes or ways to reestablish this linkage so we can perform the normal reconcilie / post operation to sync the version?

Comment: You might have the best luck contacting ESRI tech support for this. And just to verify, you actually mean a one-way replica, not a checkout/check-in replica, correct?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new checkout File GDB of the current state of the master ArcSDE geodatabase. Use the Data Comparison toolset on your new checkout File GDB against your now-disconnected checkout File GDB. Identify the edits made and bring them into your new checkout File GDB.

The Data Comparison toolset will make sure you don't miss anything (filter out the GlobalID column of course, those will be different). Then you can still take advantage of synchronization and conflict detection/resolution when you bring those edits back into the Master GDB.

An overview of the Data Comparison toolset

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/An_overview_of_the_Data_Comparison_toolset/001700000003000000/